# react-hook-form usage for simple / advanced views

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am creating a form that user can populate in either `simple` or `advanced` versions, depending on their technical expertise. If the user switches from one view to another, I'd like the **data that is present in both views to transfer** from one to the other, and if the user switches back and fwd, I'd like the **data that is only present in one of the two views to persist**.

In my mind, the easiest way to accomplish this is to initiate/"hoist" the `useForm()` hook in a parent component that holds both form-versions and then prop-drill the `register, errors, reset, etc...` That way, the form-data aka. `getValues()` will be the same between the two. However, I was told that this is not the way react-hook-form should be used.

Is this a common design pattern? Is there a better design pattern to accomplish input-data permanence and transfer between simple and advanced versions? And as a bonus, I would really appreciate if anyone pointed me to an implementation of this, or something like this.

Option Hoist in Parent

```
const parentComponent = () => {
  const [ simpleFormActive, setSimpleFormActive ] = useState(false);
  const {
    register,
    reset,
    getValues
  } = useForm();

  return (
    <>
      { simpleFormActive && 
        <SimpleForm register={ register } reset={ reset } getValues={ getValues }/>
      }
      { !simpleFormActive && 
        <AdvancedForm register={ register } reset={ reset } getValues={ getValues }/>
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d recommend creating one form state that shares the same/similar fields, but utilizes a single form context and a [Form Provider](https://react-hook-form.com/api/formprovider/).

We're using this pattern at my current job because we have a page that requires showing different forms, but those forms need to share some of the same fields. Rather than creating a bunch of different form states and trying to share & sync them across different forms, we have a single shareable/editable form state used across multiple forms (each form manages their own form submission). The other advantage of this approach is that there isn't a need for prop drilling.

Here's a simplified working example of what we have (in this example, the `email` field is persisting across all forms and will stay in sync regardless of which form it was changed in):

[image: Edit React Hook Form Shareable Fields]